# All permutations of integers corresponded to specific sum

Tags: python, recursion

I wanted to generate all permutations from the list of integers `[3,5,7,9]` which resulted in a specific sum value `15`. I implemented this, it's OK.

```
def add_next(seq, count, m):
    s = sum(seq)
    if s == m:
        count += 1
        print(seq)
    elif s < m:
        for i in [3,5,7,9]:
            add_next(seq + [i], count, m)
    else:
        return count

add_next([], 0, 15)
```

Output:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 9]
[3, 5, 7]
[3, 7, 5]
[3, 9, 3]
[5, 3, 7]
[5, 5, 5]
[5, 7, 3]
[7, 3, 5]
[7, 5, 3]
[9, 3, 3]
```

The problem is how to re-write this function to return just the number of possible permutations as a function result? Since for huge lists and big sum values it's not reasonable to generate all string outputs. I don't fully understand how to pass values inside and outside recursive function.

I tried:

```
def add_next2(seq, count, m):
    s = sum(seq)
    if s == m:
        count += 1
        print(seq)
    elif s < m:
        for i in [3,5,7,9]:
            count = add_next2(seq + [i], count, m)
    else:
        return count

add_next([], 0, 15)
```

but it retuns an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'`. So `count` is `None`. Why?

Another option is how to re-write this function to transform it to the generator and yield the output strings one after another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just counting successful recursive results, you don't need 'count' as a parameter. You can just return the successful results as 1 and unsuccessful as 0, letting them accumulate.

**EDIT 2** A little more concise but still readable

```
def add_next(seq, m):
    s = sum(seq)
    count = 1 if s == m else 0
    if s < m:
        for i in [f for f in [3,5,7,9] if s + f <= m]:
            count += add_next(seq + [i], m)
    return count

print(add_next([], 15))
```

**EDIT** You can also filter your [3,5,7,9] list so that your for i in loop only deals with elements that have a possibility of success.

```
for i in [f for f in [3,5,7,9] if s + f <= m]:
```

Comment: It's also a very good example which fix my error and suggest an imrovement! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! What if I want the function to return the permutations themselves, rather than the sum?

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive function doesn't return a value for `s <= m`. Return *something* from your function for those cases, otherwise `None` is returned instead.

Most likely you want to return `count` in all cases:

```
def add_next2(seq, count, m):
    s = sum(seq)
    if s == m:
        count += 1
    elif s < m:
        for i in [3,5,7,9]:
            count = add_next2(seq + [i], count, m)
    return count
```

This then works:

```
>>> def add_next2(seq, count, m):
...     s = sum(seq)
...     if s == m:
...         count += 1
...     elif s < m:
...         for i in [3,5,7,9]:
...             count = add_next2(seq + [i], count, m)
...     return count
... 
>>> add_next2([], 0, 15)
11
```